# Discord bot send embed message to another channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I cant figure out how to send a embedded message on a bot from one channel to another although I can figure out how to send my own message to another:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def tf1(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Test", description="1", color=0x5bcdee)
    embed.set_footer(text="Test2")
    await bot.say(discord.Object(id='456277299189383168'),  embed=embed)
```

This **doesn't seem to work** and whenever I send it I get this `<discord.object.Object object at 0x03B66BD0>` and then the embedded message.

[image]

On the other hand this **works** when I am trying to copy a message and not a embedded message, heres the code for copying my message:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def obisowner(ctx, *, mesg):
    await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='456277299189383168'), "{}".format(mesg))
```

Answer (score 2):

`bot.say()` takes a first positional argument `message`, and send the message and embed to the channel of the command context (ie. the channel of which the command message is received by the bot).

Since you want to send the message to a different channel, use `bot.send_message()` instead:

```
await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='456277299189383168'),  embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the discord.py rewrite library

First of all, you need to create the command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx):
```

After, you will need to set in which channel the message will be sent:

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(channel id)
```

Now, you need to create the embed:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed test", description="A test for my discord bot", color=0x5bcdee)
embed.add_field(name="Hello!", value="Hello World!", inline=False)
```

Finally, send the message!

```py
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Full command code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel id)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed test", description="A test for my discord bot", color=0x5bcdee)
    embed.add_field(name="Hello!", value="Hello World!", inline=False)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```