# discord.py - Send Messages on Specific Channel by Name

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make so when a message gets deleted, it sends the message that got deleted in #logs

**CODE:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
data = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print("[" + (colored("{}".format(data), 'white')) + "][" + 
  (colored("{}".format(message.server), 'blue')) + " - " + 
  (colored("{}".format(message.channel), 'magenta')) + "] " + 
  (colored("{}".format(message.author), 'cyan', 'on_magenta') + 
  (colored(": {}".format(message.content), 'red'))))
channel = bot.get_channel("logs")
await bot.say(channel, "ALERT: Message Deleted")
await bot.say(channel, "Message {} got deleted by {} in {}".format(message.content, message.author, channel))
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: See: [Send message to specific text channel by name not ID in a Python Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212308/send-message-to-specific-text-channel-by-name-not-id-in-a-python-discord-bot)

Comment: didnt help at all...

Comment: If you have a `Server` (`message.server`) and a channel name (`"logs"`), you can resolve the channel using `channel = discord.utils.get(message.server.channels, name="logs")`

Comment: You'll also have to use `bot.send_message` instead of `bot.say`.  `bot.say` only works in commands.

Comment: from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.server.channels, name="logs")
    await bot.say(channel, "Message Deleted"

TypeError: send_mesage() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments, but 4 were given

Comment: [You can't use `bot.say` outside of commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863957/discord-bot-send-embed-message-to-another-channel/50864063#50864063).  Use `bot.send_message` instead

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.